# Canvas update in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to tkinter and writing a simple skeleton program that draws five lines on a canvas. I want the canvas to be updated after each new line. I am almost there(!), but the canvas does not update until all lines have been computed. All suggestions on how to fix my code would be much appreciated. Thanks!

```
from tkinter import *
from time import sleep

class app():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.root, width=300, height=300)
        self.canvas.pack()   

        self.go()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def go(self):
        for i in range(5):
            self.drawLine(i)
            sleep(1) # simulate computation of next value

    def drawLine(self, n):
        self.canvas.create_line(0, 0, 50, n * 50 + 10)
        # now I would like canvas to be updated with the new line added

app()
```

Comment: self.root.update() at the end of drawLine method should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, now the code works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

`sleep` is incompatible with tkinter because it block the event loop. Using them together will quite often cause your tkinter window to freeze. Sleeping for five seconds may or may not cause this on your computer, but still, it's very unreliable. If you later want to display 15 lines instead of just 5, your program is almost guaranteed to stop working.

The correct solution here would be to use the `after` method of your root object. `after` executes the specified function within a certain amount of time. Here is a working example of your code:

```
from tkinter import *

class app():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.root, width=300, height=300)
        self.canvas.pack()

        self.line_counter = 0
        self.draw_next_line()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def draw_next_line(self):
        self.canvas.create_line(0, 0, 50, self.line_counter * 50 + 10)
        self.line_counter += 1
        if self.line_counter != 5:
            # call this function again after 1000 milliseconds
            self.root.after(1000, self.draw_next_line)

app()
```